# Conda Build - creating a Conda package fails on dependencies for platform win-64

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, setuptools, conda

Building my first conda package from a local dir.
following instructions from CONDA site.
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/recipe.html

i get the following error

conda_build.exception.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform win-64: set([u'pywinauto', u'statistics', u'openturns'])

I tried several items, however it seems the pywinauto, statistics and openturns are causing dependency issues.

here is my meta.yml file

```
package:
  name: apples
  version: "1.0.0"

source:
  path: ../src

target_platform:
  - win-64

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
    - statistics # [win64]
    - pywinauto # [win64]
    - openturns # [win64]
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pip
    - pyodbc
    - pyqt
    - pywin32
    - qt
    - scipy
    - tqdm
    - xlwings

  run:
    - python
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - pip
    - pyodbc
    - pyqt
    - pywin32
    - qt
    - scipy
    - tqdm
    - xlwings
    - statistics # [win64]
    - pywinauto # [win64]
    - openturns # [win64]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the packages that you use in a conda build have to be available as conda packages in one of the channels in your configuration. For your case:

- statistics and openturns are available from the `conda-forge` channel: https://anaconda.org/search?q=openturns and https://anaconda.org/search?q=statistics
- However, the `pywinauto` package is not available as a conda package, so you'll have to build your own, https://anaconda.org/search?q=pywinauto This is not too difficult to do with the `conda skeleton pypi` command

Comment: when I remove pywinauto, it fails to build, producing the same error, just with the following names (openturns, statistics), i would assume because they are on the conda-forge channel, it would just pull them normally without error. this is not the case

for the pywinauto, when I attempt to run 'conda skeleton pypi pywinauto' this returns an import error no packages found

I might just add the to bld.bat script the following
conda install -c conda-forge openturns -y
conda install -c conda-forge statistics -y
pip install pywinauto

Comment: 1. You need to add `conda-forge` to your channel list with `conda config --append channels conda-forge` before you build the package or specify the channel in the build step `conda build -c conda-forge recipe_dir`. Otherwise how does conda know where to find the package?

Comment: 2. You should definitely not do installation during the build step. How will your users get the dependencies they need if you do the installation during the build step? IIRC, conda-build actually prohibits this from happening, but that might not be correct. I know that it prohibits installing packages automatically via setuptools during the install process

Comment: 3. I had no problem running `conda skeleton pypi pywinauto` just now (although I'm running on Linux...). Maybe try again, and if it doesn't work, consider posting a new question :-) I did have a problem trying to build `pywinauto` because one of its dependencies couldn't be found. You have to do this recursively, unfortunately; every dependency has to be available as a conda package for it to work.

Comment: good call, I will not be building the install into the bld.bat as it just wont work. I already had the conda-forge channel added, and I ran a conda update all

am running now, will keep you posted. Thank You!

Comment: perhaps [conda-smithy](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-smithy) is of interest